# Identified selected ranges in Google Sheets using API

Tags: google-sheets-api, selection

I would like to use the Google Sheets API, and NOT Google Apps Script, to identify which ranges a user has selected in a Google spreadsheet. Is there a reasonable way to do this? Or do I need to use the Google Apps Script methods?

I haven't tried anything yet, because I can't find a way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: About `I would like to use the Google Sheets API, and NOT Google Apps Script, to identify which ranges a user has selected in a Google spreadsheet.`, unfortunately, in the current stage, Sheets API cannot retrieve the current user's selected ranges. In this case, the Google Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp of Google Apps Script) is required to be run on the opened Spreadsheet.